# How do I chat to friends outside a running game in starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

How can I chat to people in SC2 that are not in my current game?

I konce got a message from another ST2-friend in my game, but I couldn't answer.

I can only chat to "Allies" with <kbd>Enter</kbd> or chat to "All" with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> but not to a person from outside the currently running game.

Isn't there a button that pops up with the friends list? Or another shortcut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press "Enter" then "Tab" until your friend's name appears.

The "Tab" button will cycle through your conversations.
This is in my opinion the fastest way to chat.

Answer (score 4):

There's a few different ways.

- The /w or /m command will work for "whisper" or "message", like `/m Decency thanks!`
- Or, you can /r to "reply" to the last person to send you a message, such as `/r Playing a game at the moment`.
- Finally, you can open the friends tab in the bottom right which will allow you to message any groups or people that you've interacted with.

Answer (score 1):

If memory serves, the command is `/w [your friend's name] [your message]`.